# Get commision of a payment made wth Paypal or Striper to de app

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, paypal-permissions

Short Question: Can you split the revenue on a payment between multiple parties?

Explanation: I want to integrate payments inside an Android App, and I am liking Google Wallet as the solution. However, the app's developer wants to take a commision on the payments, and I am searching for a way to make it integrated in the app. Let's say: When a user buys a product the app's developer takes a percentage and the rest goes to the provider.

Is there a way to automatically split that payment so that a percentage reaches the developer's account and the rest goes to the provider's account? Any payment processor is capable of this? How do other developers handle this?

I did a research in paypal but are unable to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

With PayPal, if sellers [are onboarded](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/partner-referrals/v2/#definition-rest_endpoint_feature) with a third_party_details `features` that includes PARTNER_FEE, then when creating a v2/checkout/order you can [specify a `platform_fees` object.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/immediate-capture/)

In sandbox testing, the partner fee is deducted but does not go anywhere. In live it is batched 1/day to the API caller's bank account -- the batch does not enter the API caller's account as a PayPal payment, but rather goes directly to its bank.

These APIs can otherwise be tested in sandbox, but their use in live mode requires approval.